# Does the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative (for $n > 1$) tell us anything special about the function?

Tags: functions, derivatives

When the first derivative is zero, we know that the point is a local maxima or a local minima. What happens when the second, third, etc derivatives are zero? Is  anything special known about the function?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see and I think we can derive that from the Taylor expansion of the function $f$. If $f'' = 0$, what can we conclude about $f'$ at that point?

Comment: @VivaanDaga You mean the inflection point right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the mental framework of $x$ being measured in time and $f(x)$ being position.   Then $f'(x)$ measures the rate of change of position over time,  aka the velocity.

$F'(x)>0$ indicates it is going forward,  $f'(x)<0$ it is going backwards,  $f'(x)=0$ means it is (at least for a moment) still.   Thus,  the only places where we can have changes from forward to backward or visa versa are at our critical points, $f'(x)=0$ or undefined.

Your second derivative then measures the rate of change of velocity over time,  which is acceleration.   $f''>0$ means your velocity is increasing (On a graph this shows the slopes of tangent lines increasing, so you have it is concave up).   $f''<0$ is the opposite, deceleration.    Thus the only points where one can change concavity are at critical points here,  $f''=0$ or undefined.

The third derivative measures the rate of change in acceleration over time.   For physical motion, this is called the jerk.   This is because we feel it as "jerkiness".   You cannot detect velocity,  it's why riding in a plane and standing on the ground feel the same.   We feel directly the force of acceleration,   so the second derivative measures what we feel directly.   The third derivative measures how "Jerky" your ride is,   how quickly are those forces changing.

When you feel the motion of a car driving on the highway, you aren't actually feeling its velocity.  What you are feeling are all the tiny changes to acceleration by little bumps on the road/turns of the wheel, etc.

4th and higher derivatives, pretty much the only context I can give there is for taylor approximations,  you use them for fitting higher and higher degree polynomial approximates of the function near a poit.